# setting up stand alone spring batch job admin portal for existing jobs

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Currently, I have spring batch jobs developed in spring-batch 2.1

as there are so many jobs and they are running fine for a long time - so upgrading to the latest version will take some time.

Till then I want to set up spring batch admin portal have not found any firm solution so far

Comment: Spring Batch Admin is no longer supported and is not recommended for production use at this time.  Have you tried upgrading any of the jobs to the latest?  Besides the job repository change for non-identifying parameters, it may not be that difficult...

Comment: thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting it for information

decided to go further with spring cloud data flow -

we needed minimal changes in our existing spring batch jobs - so this is what we did

```
Spring batch upgrade - to - Spring batch 3.0.1
and then use -   spring-boot-starter-batch 1.1.4
```

This helped us to build a batch admin tool - with spring cloud data flow with the spring batch jobs.

We referred this blog from the Baeldung

[BATCH_Processing_with_SPRING_CLOUD_DATA_FLOW](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-batch-processing)